# Create a New Column Based on Values from Other Columns in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create new columns labelled as the values in "stno" with each containing its respective value in "qyhnd" and keeping it in order by "pano20."  So if pano20 is 6Y9807, and stno is 02, and qyhnd is 6, then my new column labelled 02 should have the value of 6 for pano20 6Y9807. The examples of what I currently have and what I am trying to achieve are below. Thanks

What I have now:

| PANO20 | QYHND | STNO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6Y9807 | 6 | 02 |
| 6N3191 | 8 | 01 |
| 1476605 | 15 | 02 |
| 1672190 | 6 | 01 |
| 2641440 | 2 | 00 |

I am trying to get:

| PANO20 | QYHND | STNO | 00 | 01 | 02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6Y9807 | 6 | 02 |  |  | 6 |
| 6N3191 | 8 | 01 |  | 8 |  |
| 1476605 | 15 | 02 |  |  | 15 |
| 1672190 | 6 | 01 |  | 6 |  |
| 2641440 | 2 | 00 | 2 |  |  |

This is my attempt:

```sql
select ps.PANO20, ps.SOS1, ps.QYHND, ps.QYOR, ps.MIN, ps.MAX, ps.STNO, ps.SKNSKI, ms.SOS1, ms.UNCS, SUM (DMMO01+ DMMO02+ DMMO03+ DMMO04+ DMMO05+ DMMO06+ DMMO07+ DMMO08+ DMMO09+ DMMO10+ DMMO11+ DMMO12) as [Demand12]
from LIBH07.dbo.PCPPIST0 ps 
inner join LIBCOM500.dbo.PCPPRMS0 ms
on ps.PANO20 = ms.PANO20
where ps.STNO IN  ('00','01','02','03') and ps.SOS1 = '000' and ms.SOS1 = '000' 
group by ps.SOS1, ps.PANO20, qyhnd, qyor, MIN, MAX, stno, sknski, ms.sos1, ms.UNCS
order by PANO20 desc
```

```sql
create table OnHandStore
as select PANO20,
SUM(case when stno = '00' then qyhnd end) as Henderson,
SUM(case when stno = '01' then qyhnd end) as Reno, 
SUM(case when stno = '02' then qyhnd end) as Elko,
SUM(case when stno = '03' then qyhnd end) as Winnemucca, 
from pcppist0 as t1
group by PANO20;
```

Comment: Have a look at [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @ThomA I am trying to add what sql I have currently but it's not allowing me to I did have case though let me see if I'm able to add it as text as it won't allow me via code format

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/JTegPpV2 Try this @ThomA

Comment: `CREATE TABLE...AS` isn't valid T-SQL; that looks like MySQL.

Comment: Why would you remove the SQL after I added it for you..?

Comment: @ThomA Got it, okay so I am just looking to add the columns to the current joined table. What would be the correct statement?

Comment: I didn't see that you added anything I apologize I had a lot of tabs open and may have done it by accident @ThomA

Comment: if you want create view ,you must use "Create view " instead of "Create table" and Remove "," at end "create view OnHandStore
as select PANO20,
SUM(case when stno = '00' then qyhnd end) as Henderson,
SUM(case when stno = '01' then qyhnd end) as Reno, 
SUM(case when stno = '02' then qyhnd end) as Elko,
SUM(case when stno = '03' then qyhnd end) as Winnemucca
from pcppist0 as t1
group by PANO20;"

Comment: for first query ,i need structure and example data and expected to solve your problem

Comment: So I am joining two tables by part number, after the join, I need to add the columns referenced in my initial question.  All of the columns needed to form this come from the original table pcppist0. Here is the new query I have, and I get an error of "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'." Do I need to do this before the join of the two tables pcppist0 and pcpprms0?

Comment: if whole columns use is pcppist0  table,you can subquery(my query) insted of original pcppist,if you want insert to other table ,you must use into before select "select * into [NewTable] from"

Answer (score 0):

As @ThomA said you can do this with a case expression

```
select 
         PANO20
         ,QYHND
         ,STNO
         ,(case when STNO='00' then QYHND else '' end ) as '00'
        ,(case when STNO='01' then QYHND else '' end ) as '01'
        ,(case when STNO='02' then QYHND else '' end ) as '02'
from TT
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/quqRmzBt)

Comment: This is very similar to the code I currently have. Do I need a "group by" pano20; at the end?

Comment: Also this is a merged table, so when I am selecting "from" how to I specify the current set?

Comment: For your example, you don't need group, but you need to group, you can use group by(if you have new record "2641440" need show only 1 record ,you need group by ),if you need group by must specify  QYHND is sum or max or min

Comment: I am going to add the sql I have by asking a new question and will reference it here. I keep getting errors that I can not edit my question.

Comment: if you two or multi table ,you must use join "please show query that i can help you",if you union ,you use subquery after use my query"select *,case ... from(
select PANO20,QYHND,STNO from t union select PANO20,QYHND,STNO from t2
)"

Comment: Here is what I have currently https://dbfiddle.uk/JTegPpV2

Answer (score 0):

You  can use aggregation or pivot

```
CREATE TABLE pcppist0
    (PANO20 varchar(7), [QYHND] int, [stno] varchar(2))
;
    
INSERT INTO pcppist0
    (PANO20, QYHND, stno)
VALUES
    ('6Y9807', 6, '02'),
    ('6N3191', 8, '01'),
    ('1476605', 15, '02'),
    ('1672190', 6, '01'),
    ('2641440', 2, '00')
;
```

```
5 rows affected
```

```
 select PANO20,

   SUM(case when stno = '00' then qyhnd ELSE 0 end)  as Henderson,
SUM(case when stno = '01' then qyhnd ELSE 0 end) as Reno, 
SUM(case when stno = '02' then qyhnd ELSE 0 end) as Elko,
SUM(case when stno = '03' then qyhnd ELSE 0 end) as Winnemucca 
   INTO OnHandStore
from pcppist0 as t1
group by PANO20;
```

```
5 rows affected
```

```
  SELECT * FROM OnHandStore
```

| PANO20 | Henderson | Reno | Elko | Winnemucca |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1476605 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 0 |
| 1672190 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 2641440 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6N3191 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| 6Y9807 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |

```
 select PANO20,
   [00] As Henderson, [01] as Reno , [02] as  Elko, [03] as Winnemucca
   INTO OnHandStore1
   from pcppist0 as t1
PIVOT  
(  
  MAX(qyhnd)  
  FOR stno IN ([00], [01], [02], [03])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

```
5 rows affected
```

```
  SELECT * FROM OnHandStore1
```

| PANO20 | Henderson | Reno | Elko | Winnemucca |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1476605 | *null* | *null* | 15 | *null* |
| 1672190 | *null* | 6 | *null* | *null* |
| 2641440 | 2 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 6N3191 | *null* | 8 | *null* | *null* |
| 6Y9807 | *null* | *null* | 6 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kLAo3ovG)

Comment: Only problem with this is that I have about 400k "pano20's" so I can't specify as you did in the first section

Comment: 200000 are no problem 2 mio also no problem, with more st_no you would get a problem, as you would need to define all in a max statementm but then you have to use dynamic sql like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: I am going to add the sql I have by asking a new question and will reference it here. I keep getting errors that I can not edit my question.

Comment: don't forget to delete this one

Comment: Its okay, I just did a fiddle please look here https://dbfiddle.uk/JTegPpV2

Comment: Sum is more difficult as NULL can not be summed see https://dbfiddle.uk/WnuAEcb4 and ou have a typo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254106/discussion-between-lberecek-and-nbk).